# API + Application insights trace

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've got an API written in dotnet6, hosted in Azure with an Application Insights configured and connected. I've also included the AppInsights sdk for .NET

I'm struggling to get see a dependency graph for the initial HTTP call.

For example,

API > Calls into Object 1's method > Calls into Object 2's method > Calls into a database and passes the result back up the chain and eventually back to the controller and out to the caller.

I've placed a logging statements throughout the methods using ILogger via DI. I can see these in Application Insights but only one after the other. What what I'm after is a dependency graph... eg, clicking in app insights the original HTTP call and see what associated logging statements have made triggered.

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried? and share the exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling to get see a dependency graph for the initial HTTP call

I have created a web application using Dotnet 6.0 and configured Application Insights with an instrumentation key.
Using the code below, I successfully logged dependencies to Application Insights.

**program.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Access app configuration
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Add Application Insights telemetry
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]);

// Enable dependency tracking
builder.Services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) =>
{
    module.EnableLegacyCorrelationHeadersInjection = true;
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "your instrumentation key"
  }
}
```

[image]

In Application Insights, the dependencies were successfully triggered in the dependency graph. Check below:
**Output:**

[image]

[image]